# Terminal title shows sudo, but I want command that's sudo'ed

Tags: bash, gentoo, profile

So I've become pretty adept at the tasks here from editing all the posts to answering questions, so I think it's about time I ask one:

### Technical Information

Distribution: Gentoo
Desktop Environment: KDE
Terminal Emulator: Kterm

### Problem

Anyone who uses Gentoo for a long time gets used to a terminal and source code floating by.  As such, I've come to depend on the terminal even in KDE with commands like:

- `kdesudo kate /etc/portage/make.conf`
- `sudo emerge -uDav world`

These commands work as expected, my issue here is that kterm's title shows `username:sudo`  **I want it to show username:sudo elevated command, or username:elavated command**.

I use the following profile:

```
# /etc/profile: login shell setup
#
# That this file is used by any Bourne-shell derivative to setup the
# environment for login shells.
#

# Load environment settings from profile.env, which is created by
# env-update from the files in /etc/env.d
if [ -e /etc/profile.env ] ; then
    . /etc/profile.env
fi

# You should override these in your ~/.bashrc (or equivalent) for per-user
# settings.  For system defaults, you can add a new file in /etc/profile.d/.
export EDITOR=${EDITOR:-/bin/nano}
export PAGER=${PAGER:-/usr/bin/less}

# 077 would be more secure, but 022 is generally quite realistic
umask 022

# Set up PATH depending on whether we're root or a normal user.
# There's no real reason to exclude sbin paths from the normal user,
# but it can make tab-completion easier when they aren't in the
# user's PATH to pollute the executable namespace.
#
# It is intentional in the following line to use || instead of -o.
# This way the evaluation can be short-circuited and calling whoami is
# avoided.
if [ "$EUID" = "0" ] || [ "$USER" = "root" ] ; then
    PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:${ROOTPATH}"
else
    PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:${PATH}"
fi
export PATH
unset ROOTPATH

if [ -n "${BASH_VERSION}" ] ; then
    # Newer bash ebuilds include /etc/bash/bashrc which will setup PS1
    # including color.  We leave out color here because not all
    # terminals support it.
    if [ -f /etc/bash/bashrc ] ; then
        # Bash login shells run only /etc/profile
        # Bash non-login shells run only /etc/bash/bashrc
        # Since we want to run /etc/bash/bashrc regardless, we source it 
        # from here.  It is unfortunate that there is no way to do 
        # this *after* the user's .bash_profile runs (without putting 
        # it in the user's dot-files), but it shouldn't make any 
        # difference.
        . /etc/bash/bashrc
    else
        PS1='\u@\h \w \$ '
    fi
else
    # Setup a bland default prompt.  Since this prompt should be useable
    # on color and non-color terminals, as well as shells that don't
    # understand sequences such as \h, don't put anything special in it.
    PS1="${USER:-$(whoami 2>/dev/null)}@$(uname -n 2>/dev/null) \$ "
fi

for sh in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
    [ -r "$sh" ] && . "$sh"
done
unset sh
```

I will insert my `etc/bashrc/bashrc` file here when I return home...

---

I left the comments to give the new users here a stab at an answer.  As  such, the most thorough answer that works will be awarded points even if your new here.  I want a properly formatted answer with References and Links

### Update

[image: Kterm image]

Comment: Ill research tomorrow and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about `kterm`, but probably it is `xterm` escape compatible - most are. If so, then you'll want to put something in your prompt that [sets the window title](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-3.html):

- 3.1 xterm escape sequences
- Window and icon titles may be changed in a running xterm by using XTerm escape sequences. The following sequences are useful in this respect:

  - `ESC]0;stringBEL` -- Set icon name and window title to string
  - `ESC]1;stringBEL` -- Set icon name to string
  - `ESC]2;stringBEL` -- Set window title to string
- ...where `ESC` is the escape character (`\033`), and `BEL` is the bell character (`\007`).

You can put these in your prompt between the non-printing escape - if you're using `bash`. In that shell you can use:

```
PS1="\[$(printf '\033]0;"${USER}@${BASH_COMMAND}"\007')\]"
```

Or you can put something like that in your `$PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable.

#### BUT...

[Apparently](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=179142) `konsole` has varied by version as to whether it will allow setting the window name by way of escape sequence. At some point during its version 3 cycle it stopped interpreting the `ESC]33;Window nameBEL` sequence and honored the `xterm` sequences only for altering the tab titles.

Since [version 4.9](http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=konsole.git&a=commit&h=363a2701774ffd0b14bfd8223a5848179a427bd6), though, `konsole` should at least honor the weird `ESC]30;Tab NameBEL` sequence, and if you configure it as empty in the settings dialog, then the window name will automatically be cloned from the currently active tab.

I'm unclear as to whether you can use the more common `xterm` escapes to set the window title or not. If the information offered here is not enough to arrive at a satisfactory solution, however, then I suspect you'll find some useful information by clicking through the links attached to the relevant changes recorded for version 4.9 in the [changelog here](https://konsole.kde.org/changelog.php).

Comment: See [KDE Forum - konsole: How to set different window title and tab title?](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=89834)  Looks like your fix will only update the Tab title

Comment: @eyoung100 - do you mean you cannot change the display of ***username: sudo*** to ***whatever you want*** with the escape sequences mentioned? In other words, you see ***both*** *username:sudo* and *whatever you want* using the above methods? I was only attempting to answer the question asked - which is how to replace the mentioned string with a string of your choosing. If your terminal doesn't support an escape sequence for setting the window title itself, then you might look at `xprop`, `xwininfo`, and/or `xdotool`. If you'll take my advice, you'll ditch the KDE bloat and get Enlightenment.

Comment: I'd like Enlightenment but E17 on Gentoo is a pain :)

Comment: @eyoung100 - you want e19 - and you can get the packages from their website - there are 5. E17 used to be like 15 packages - but most are now consolidated in `efl`. You want `efl`, `elementary`, `enlightenment`, `evas generic loaders`, and `emotion generic players` - in that order. That's the entire suite - but if you like yourself you'll add `terminology`. If you use the packages on their site it's as simple as verifying deps *(like `bullet` and some common xlibs)* then `make && make install` for each.

Comment: @eyoung100 - `enlightenment` aside - you didn't answer the question about the title change. Do you see both the *username: sudo* title *and* the tab title, or do the escapes change the text asked about? Have you since realized you would prefer a different behavior - if so what exactly? It might be I can help, it's just that I'm unclear now about the nature of the problem.

Comment: I see my username, a colon, and the word sudo.  I just read that forum post I linked to earlier, and according to that the Window title cannot be changed, only the Tab title.

Comment: @eyoung100 - you see that where and under what circumstances? You see that in the window title and not in the tab title? You see that after setting `$PS1` as recommended?

Comment: See image in update.  According to that forum post above, applying the fix you recommend would only Change the Tab title but not the Window Title

Comment: @eyoung100 - cool! I see there are `portage` scripts for e19, huh? I typically compile updates from `git` myself and the process usually takes less than 10 mins. `user - bash` seems to be both the window and icon title - but I see no tab title and am still unsure of the `$PS1` value in context. Also weird is that `bash` is the title, but it seems obvious some cmd was run since you opened `kterm`. I assumed some prompt escape was setting it to *latest cmd* - else how would it change at all? Does it change? Maybe we'll just wait and see how you like `terminology` *(hint - you will)* 1st, though.

Comment: I can install e19 via git if I use the version number 9999.  Gentoo allows this for all packages that have a git repo.  In case you're interested see the [Gentoo - Enlightenment Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Enlightenment) .  Read the section on live ebuilds.  If you're interested see also: [The Gentoo Handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:Main_Page).  I can't convert many people here because compiling the entire system from scratch turns most people off.  I'm off to bed :)

Comment: @eyoung100 - i like Arch - but the majority of major packages installed to my system are compiled locally by way of the [Arch Build System](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Build_System). Anyway, let me know how you like enlightenment after a few days, yeah? Also - see the update to the answer if it's still relevant.